# dd-wrt switch for PfSense

Tags: networking, switch, pfsense, router

I currently have eth2 on my pfsense set up, and configured as 192.168.1.1, it has dhcp setup with allocation being 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.245.

On my dd-wrt box, i disabled the WAN, and set it to act as a port for the switch.  I disabled dhcp, dnsmasq, spi firewall, Wlan0 and set a static IP for the router being 192.168.1.10

Pfsense is plugged into lan0 and pc plugged into lan1 (wan port is empty)

I have followed a few different guides, but i can't seem to get my router to act as a switch.

Anyone have success using DD-WRT as a switch while using pfsense as your dhcp/dns/gateway.

Any advice would help :)

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that you're dd-wrt address is the first address of your DHCP scope.  Any clients looking for DHCP assignment would probably get that address first.  Change your dd-wrt switch ip to something below .10.

Also verify that Lan0 and Lan1 are in the same bridge group on DD-WRT.  Easy way to test this is to set a static ip on the pc and see if you can ping .1 (pfsense).

If they can ping each-other then your dd-wrt(switch) should be working and your problem would be on the pfsense for not responding properly to DHCP.